# How to get the user's identity in Elsa Workflows?

Tags: elsa-workflows

I set up Elsa Workflows Core in an ASP.NET Core app, with authentication for HTTP requests.

I have an `HttpEndpoint` activity, authentication is enforced, but I can't see any way to obtain the user's identity within the workflow.

The `HttpContext` object doesn't seem to be available. I can get the `HttpRequestModel` using `GetInput()`, but `HttpRequestModel` doesn't contain this information.

I'm using Microsoft AD authentication, but the question applies to any auth scheme.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using dependency injection and running in a ASP.NET Core app, simply use constructor injection to get at `IHttpContextAccessor`.

```
class YourClass 
{
    public YourClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
    // ...
}
```

However this tightly couples your class with the HTTP context. You could create a view around it to return the things you need:

```
interface IUserAccessor
{
   User User { get; }
}
class HttpContextUserAccessor : IUserAccessor
{
   public YourClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext) //...
   public User User { get; } // implement using httpContext
}
class YourClass 
{
    public YourClass(IUserAccessor userAccessor)
    // ...
}
```

Also, it looks like [Elsa has this pattern.](https://elsa-workflows.github.io/elsa-core/docs/next/guides/guides-workflow-contexts#workflow-context)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I was hoping Elsa had a way to give it to me natively.

Comment: It didn't work. I did get a `HttpContext` object, but the User.Identity object didn't have any meaningful data in it (it existed, but everything was `null`.) It's the right context, it has the path and headers etc.
From a regular controller or page it worked fine, so the auth is working - but it looks like it's been wiped by the time I need it.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. The answer is [here](https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core/blob/master/src/samples/aspnet/Elsa.Samples.HttpEndpointSecurity/Workflows/SecureHelloWorkflow.cs), in one of their samples.

Daniel put me on the right track, but my main problem was that I had `.UseHttpActivities()` before `.UseAuthentication()` in the Startup file.